# Nginx caching files from S3 updated using crontab

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3, nginx-config

I have a case where I use Nginx to serve static files in `/var/www/html`. This is my config:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html ;
        }

}
```

I'm updating the `var/www/html` content every 5 minutes using a crontab task:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/aws s3 sync s3://my_bucket /var/www/html --delete
```

And the files are updated properly. New files are coming in and deleted files are being removed.

After crontab task I see changes in file system on the server but not on the client accessed via www. I thought it might be Nginx cache issue but restarting Nginx or even the whole server doesn't help. Clearing browser caches doesn't work us well.

I can see the newest changes only if I empty `/var/www/html` directory with `rm -rf *` command and manually sync it again with S3 - although the files are exactly the same as before s3 sync.

What could be causing this behaviour?

Comment: do you have a storage gateway in aws? that can possibly help to automatically refresh the cache every X minutes

Comment: I don't have storage gateway. And I don't want any cache. I want up-to-date files as soon as I can.
Anyway I have newest files on server's disk but Nginx is not picking them up :/ And that's my issue here.

Comment: you can do more research based on the context here https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/storage-gateway-s3-changes-not-showing

Comment: But how storage gateway is relevant in my case?

Answer (score 0):

Your cronjob command seems correct.

Try to disable the nginx caching globally.

```
server {
    ...
    proxy_cache off; # It turns off proxy caching, which disables NGINX's built-in caching mechanism.
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_cache_control;# It bypasses caching based on the Cache-Control header in the response. It ensures that responses containing Cache-Control headers with specific values are not cached.
    add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"; #This line sets the Cache-Control header in NGINX responses to ensure that clients (browsers) do not cache the content. The values "no-cache," "no-store," and "must-revalidate" instruct the client not to cache the content and to revalidate it with the server for each request.
    expires off; #It turns off the use of the Expires header, which would otherwise specify a date in the future for when the content can be considered stale and should be re-fetched from the server.
    ...
}
```